# RMarkdown visual mode doesn't print the plots or output when runnning the chunks

Tags: r-markdown

I did a RMarkdown file, if I knit the file I can see everything normally.

However when I go to visual mode, I only see the code which I have it as true to show but I don't see the result output for example if I print plots.

What can I do to fix this? It is not an issue of the code, because when I knit the file I can see all outputs normally.

This is what I se in the visual mode in Rstudio:
[image]

This is what I am supposed to see or what I see when knitting:
[image]